# Loading woocommerce images from sub-domain

Tags: php, wordpress, optimization, woocommerce

Trying to optimize a wordpress site. When a browser requests static images, it sends cookies with the request from the main domain, but the server ignores the cookies. These cookies are unnecessary network traffic. To workaround these issues, I am trying to make sure that static components are requested with cookie-free requests by creating a subdomain. And it also helps in parallel requests thereby loading my site faster.

I created the subdomain accordingly, I changed the the uploads_image_path in the "wp-admin/options.php". And every image seems to be redirecting to my subdomain, except all my woocommerce images.

Example:

```
example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/image_name.jpg
```

should change to

```
uploads.example.com/2018/07/image_name.jpg
```

If I can't redirect my my woocommerce images, it renders that one strategy absolute, because woocommerce contains most of my images. Am I missing something?

Comment: can you please share code you have tried so far

Comment: Something is wrong here. WooCommerce actually does not actually save image URLs (or image file paths). It saves the attachment ids. If you view the meta_values of the post_meta for meta_keys '_thumbnail_id' and '_product_image_gallery' you will find that the values are attachment ids of attachments in the media library. So WooCommerce product images are really images in WordPress's Media Library and should use the same upload directory. Your strategy should work. There is something else wrong.

Comment: @allenski. its not a code based solution I did, more of a process. 1. add sub-domain 2. Change database instances.

Comment: @S.V your set of thinking was right. Conclusively my path was not being saved from wordpress. and also a "search and replace" on the databse would only replace current values but does not change the path. So you need to look for the path values inside the options and set them.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, changing the path on "example.com/wp-admin/options.php"  does not write permanent changes ". I had to go directly to the options table in the database, change the the values for "upload_url_path" and "upload_path"  to my subdomain.